# using sessions to display values in another page from a looping textbox

Tags: php, session

This is my page1.php. It has a textbox that loops. When user clicks the button, it goes to page2.php

```
<?php 
  for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {               
    Full Name : <input type='text' name='txtName' />
  } ?>
  <input type="submit" name="Proceed" value="Proceed" class="button" />

<?php
  $name = $_POST['txtName'];
  if(isset($_POST['Proceed'])) {
    for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    if(!empty($name[$i])) {
      session_start(); 
          $_SESSION['nme'] = $name; 
          header("Location: page2.php");
     } } }
?>
```

This is my page2.php where it should display data from looping textbox

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $naming = $_SESSION['nme'];

  $length = count($naming);
  for($i=0; $i< $length; $i++){    
    echo $naming." &nbsp; ";
  }
?>
```

Problem is that it is only displaying the last data from the textbox. It isn't displaying all the values from textbox.

Comment: yes it is in a for loop

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a text box that loops? Because your above for loop only prints the text box twice. Both text boxes have the same 'name' so its likely that one text box value is overriding the other in your $_SESSION variables. http://phpfiddle.org/ Would help a ton.